# (android) rows of buttons that take up the entire width of the screen

Tags: android, layout, button, rows

I am trying to make 3 rows of 4 buttons each that will take up the entire width of the screen. I have tried Linear Layout but have trouble adding a second row and from what I have read nesting Linear Layouts is bad practice. I tried to use relative layout several times but I cannot manage to get the buttons to fill the width of the screen because it ignores layout_weight, I then tried nesting linear layout in relative layout but layout_weight is still ignored.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `TableRow` and you should be fine.

Comment: @valon If the solution worked for you, you should consider accepting this answer.